# JavaService and QTP

Tags: java, qtp

Can I test/call a Java Service from QTP and how?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the QTP Service Test add-in which is used for testing "non GUI-based services."

Answer (score 0):

You can also test directly from VBScript in QTP, without the Service Test add-in.  See this [SQAForums](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=434429) post.

Answer (score -1):

**To call the jar fil**e:

To call the jar file, you can use QTP’s SystemUtil.Run like this:

SystemUtil.Run “cmd”,”/c java -jar parsingclass.jar”,””

**To call the java class:**

For a java class you would do something like this:

SystemUtil.Run “cmd”,”/K java D:\HL7Parser\bin\CORUExtractorFlow1151.class”,””

**Explanation About the Code:**

SystemUtil Object is a QTP object that can be used to control an application or process during a test run.

The Run method runs a file or application. cmd starts a new instance of a command interpreter.

/K is a parameter that runs the command and leaves the command window open. (If you want to close the command window instead of keeping it open, you would need to replace the /K parameters with the /C parameter.) For more info on CMD and its parameters, check out Microsoft’s documentation website

For move complicate Java calls

If you have a more complicated Java DLL that you need to interact with, you could use Service Test 11, which contains a call java class activity. With a “Unified Functional license ,” you could call Service Test from QTP; in our case, however, this would have been overkill, so we kept it simple by using the method described above.